# What are alternatives now for showinfo since it's been deprecated?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have a Youtube video embedded on our Learning Management System that needs to have sharing disabled. Now that showinfo no longer works, what other options do I have?

Comment: Based on their announcement, so far, there is no alternative. As they have already declared that *"The behavior for the `rel` parameter is changing on or after September 25, 2018. The effect of the change is that you will not be able to disable related videos"*. You may want to try their suggestion instead *"However, you will have the option of specifying that the related videos shown in the player should be from the same channel as the video that was just played"*.